# Rewrite any subdomain to directory with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

Basically I want to make something like this:

User enters in browser: https://user1.example.com/ (or any subdomain)

It shows the content of: https://example.com/user1

I searched the whole internet for a solution for this, but none work, it is always showing "We can't resolve the IP address of the server https://user1.example.com/" and I could only figure out, that I have to use rewrite in .htaccess

Comment: *"We can't find the IP address of the server"* that *sounds* more like a DNS issue.

Comment: Pretty sure you cant achieve this without actually setting up the dns zone for the subdomain itself

Comment: yesi think its a dns error but how should i solve that.

Comment: As a quick hack/test you could add a line to your system hosts file, something like `123.123.123.123    user1.example.com` - that should override DNS resolution for that sub-domain.

Comment: By all means I'm no expert but I'm pretty sure you don't need to setup DNS for a subdomain. The IP that it's routed to is always the URL of the top level domain eg. `example` in `user1.example.com`. This may be completely wrong but I'm pretty sure this is the case

Comment: @DrRoach, you are wrong, and this needs to be specifically defined in the DNS, either as a `A`, `AAAA` or `CNAME` record for `user1.example.com` or a wilcard record `*.example.com` that will match anything, which is useful (but also loaded with problems) when you want "dynamic" subdomains. If you go to `http://user1.example.com/` the browser asks for `user1.example.com` in the DNS and by default does not fallback to `example.com`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i think thats the solution, I'll try that

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%1
```

Comment: still getting the same error: "Can't find resolve IP"

Comment: Have you got your virtual hosts setup to correctly? And the re-write extension installed? Also have you made sure to allow mod_rewrites in your htaccess? I'm not 100% sure about the `https` at the start of the rule. Maybe try without that if it's still not working?

Comment: You can not match against full URL in `RewriteRule` . Only URL path is allowed.

Comment: @starkeen I thought that may be the case, updated answer to what i believe? is correct. May be able to change `HTTP_HOST` to `HTTPS_HOST` but again I'm unsure.